# Networkx: how to use node_match argument in optimize_graph_edit_distance?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to compare two graphs with the help of the `optimize_graph_edit_distance` algorithm on NetworkX:

```
optimize_graph_edit_distance(G1, G2,
    node_match=None,
    node_subst_cost=None,
    edge_match=None,
    node_del_cost=None,
    edge_subst_cost=None,
    edge_del_cost=None,
    edge_ins_cost=None,
    upper_bound=None)
```

I gave each node on both graphs a set amount of attributes in the form of a dictionary and with the help of `node_match` I can specify if nodes N1 and N2 should be considered equal during matching.

The function `node_match` should be called like so:

```
node_match(G1.nodes[n1], G2.nodes[n2])  >>n1 and n2 are node attribute dictionaries as input.
```

My problem is that I have more than one node in each graph. Therefore, how do I give the function all other attribute dictionaries to compare all other nodes?

Answer (score 2):

`node_match` is a function that returns True if node n1 in G1 and n2 in G2 should be considered equal during matching. For example:

```
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_nodes_from([(0, {'label':'a'}), (1, {'label':'b'}),(2, {'label':'c'})])
G1.add_edges_from([(0,1),(0,2)])

G2 = nx.DiGraph()
G2.add_nodes_from([(3, {'label':'a'}), (4, {'label':'b'}),(5, {'label':'c'})])
G2.add_edges_from([(3,4),(3,5)])

print(G1.nodes())
print(G1.edges())

print(G2.nodes())
print(G2.edges())

for dist in nx.algorithms.similarity.optimize_graph_edit_distance(G1, G2, node_match=lambda a,b: a['label'] == b['label']):
    print(dist)
```

Here, even though the node identifiers in the two graphs are different, the distance will be zero. That's because we defined the function that compares 2 nodes as `lambda a,b: a['label'] == b['label']`, meaning that two nodes are considered equal during matching if they have the same 'label' value.

Similarly, you can implement any logic you wish to without specifically treating every pair of nodes in your graphs.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Would it be possible to compare multiple Nodes with multiple Attributes as well?

Comment: The comparison is always between pairs of nodes (the function should decide wether it's the same node or not), and you can define the logic according to many attributes ('a' and 'b' are simply dictionaries, each with all the node's attributes, so you are not limited with how to use it for comparing the nodes).